# socket.on() not receiving data

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I am having a problem with getting socket.on to work

```
$('#showmsg').click(function() {
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
var msgText = $('#msgtext');
socket.emit('show msg', msgText.val());
});
```

That code works, as shown by using

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('show msg', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

in server.js, my main app file, however in another file, when I use the code

```
    $(document).ready(function (){
        var socket = io.connect();
        socket.on('show msg', function(data) {
            $('#container').hide();
        });
    });
```

Nothing happens. Does anyone know how I can get this code to work?

Answer (score 1):

When you connect in the client, you have to wait for the `connect` message before you can send data with `.emit()`.  As you have it now, you are trying to send the data before the connection has finished so the data is lost.

See the client-side example here: http://socket.io/docs/#sending-and-getting-data-(acknowledgements)

Answer (score 1):

I think what's happening is that in your document.ready function, you are trying to call io.connect() but you are then calling the show message before your socket has connected. Try doing it like this

```
socket.on('connect', function (){
   socket.on('show msg', function(data) {
        $('#container').hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing happens because you don't emit anything.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
  socket.on('show msg', function(data) {
    $('#container').hide();
  });
  socket.emit('show msg', 'right now I am emitting data');
});
```